# In UiButton ImageView.alpha is changed after click event, how to keep previous alpha?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibutton

I have a UIButton with image (default imageView for UIButton).

After creation and layout i set:

```
button.imageView?.alpha = 0.3
```

and everything works.

But after button tap action, picture is fully visible again, and aplha value is changed.

Hot to prevent it, to have the same aplha value after button tapped action?

Answer (score 0):

I guess UIButton can change properties of its default subviews when the button is changing its state.

I'd suggest two options:

1. Use subclass of UIButton and override `isHighligted` property:

```
class MyButton: UIButton {
    override var isHighlighted: Bool {
        didSet {
            imageView?.alpha = 0.3
        }
    }
}
```

2. Or implement custom UIControl instead of UIButton. You can add and use your custom subviews and define how you want them to behave. Also you can use the same UIControl target actions as UIButton has (.touchUpInside, .touchDown etc.)

```
class MyButton: UIControl {
    
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this, delete/comment button.imageView?.alpha = 0.3 alpha:

```
let button: UIButton = {
let b = UIButton(type: .system)
    b.imageView?.image = yourImage
    // b.imageView?.alpha = 0.3 
    b.addTarget(self, action: #selector(yourAction), for: .touchUpInside)
 return b
}()
```

now in viewDidLoad:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    changeAlpha()
}
var alphaControl = 0

@objc func changeAlpha() {
 if alphaControl == 0 {
 button.imageView?.alpha = 0.3
 alphaControl = 1
} else {
 button.imageView?.alpha = 1 // or all alpha that do you want
  alphaControl = 0
 }
}
```

after that you can call the function changeAlpha() in all your button action.

You can add animation in it and add some else if or make a switch

Comment: This is not a solution, i've already tried it, it must be changed somehow after onClick function is called.

Comment: @JanekWojciechowski try to delete/comment the first button.imageView?.alpha = 0.3 attribute and call the func changeAlpha() in viewDidLoad, naturally delete the call for  goToYourButtonAction() function

Comment: @JanekWojciechowski I edited my example answer, take a look and try it...